# Oracle DB: Query is returning less results than expected

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I'm trying to that query on Oracle DB. I need show client name (1st column), how many times client located a video in month 08 (2nd column), how many times located a video in month 09 (3rd column), how many times located a video in month 10 (4th column)

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.NOMECLI, COUNT(DISTINCT B.DATALOC) AS MESOITO, COUNT(DISTINCT C.DATALOC) AS MESNOVE, COUNT(DISTINCT D.DATALOC) AS MESDEZ FROM TBCLIENTE A
LEFT JOIN TBLOCACAO B ON A.PKCODCLI = B.FKCODCLI AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM B.DATALOC) = '08'
LEFT JOIN TBLOCACAO C ON A.PKCODCLI = C.FKCODCLI AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM C.DATALOC) = '09'
LEFT JOIN TBLOCACAO D ON A.PKCODCLI = D.FKCODCLI AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM D.DATALOC) = '10'
GROUP BY A.NOMECLI;
```

but the result is wrong, because two of three count columns are showing less results that are in DB.
Can you see what is wrong at the query? There is another way to make the query?

Comment: Perhaps you can add your table structures, sample data, current result for that sample, and the result you expect to see?

Comment: (1) you don't need the first `DISTINCT` if you're grouping by that column and (2) the other `DISTINCT`s could be the reason you're seeing lower counts than expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query counted distinct `dataloc`, so probably this is the reason you get less results than you wanted.
You can write this simpler (with Oracle 11g):

```
select * from (
    select c.pkcodcli, c.nomecli, extract(month from dataloc) mth
      from tbcliente c join tblocacao l on l.fkcodcli = c.pkcodcli)
  pivot (count(mth) for mth in (8 as "MESOITO", 9 as "MESNOVE", 10 as "MESDEZ"));
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b0a59/1)